# if statement for no image in facebook app clone

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm making a facebook clone just for fun, but I can't seem to be able to make different types of posts (status, photos, videos).

this is my object for a photo post

```
    class Post {
    var name: String?
    var profileImageName: String?
    var statusText: String?
    var statusImageName: String?
    var numLikes: Int?
    var numComments: Int?
}
```

if I don't assign an image name to this post, it uses an image from another post, so I'm not able to create status post.

How can I do this? Do I have to create another class? And if so, How do I make the function:

`override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { }`

recognize the status post and create the right number of cells in the Colletion View?

PS: Is it ok to use UICollectionView in this case or should I use something else?

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let feedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    feedCell.post = posts[indexPath.item]

    return feedCell




    let postGandhi = Post()
    postGandhi.name = "Mahatma Gandhi"
    postGandhi.profileImageName = "gandhi_profile"
    postGandhi.statusText = "Live as if you were to die tomorrow; learn as if you were to live forever.\n" +
        "The weak can never forgive. Forgiveness is the attribute of the strong.\n" +
    "Happiness is when what you think, what you say, and what you do are in harmony."
    postGandhi.statusImageName = "gandhi_status"
    postGandhi.numLikes = 333
    postGandhi.numComments = 22


posts.append(postGandhi)
```

and then I use NSLayoutConstraints to add everything

Comment: Can you show your code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ? You probably aren't setting the image to `nil` when the cell is reused and there isn't a photo

Comment: @paulw11 you should post the bit about cellForRowAtIndexPath as an answer. That is almost certainly the problem. You always have to fully configure your cells since they may have contents left over from the last time they were used.

Comment: I've added the cellForItemATIndexPath @Paulw11

Comment: How do you actually set the image view?  Do you have a setter on the `post` property?  Can you show that?

Comment: @Paulw11 is that what u meant?

Comment: No,  in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you say `feedCell.post = posts[indexPath.item]` but this doesn't actually assign anything to the image view or text views in the cell.  Show the code where you actually assign the image to the imageview.